# Scaling inserting related optional objects to your collection

Tags: object-oriented, architectural-patterns

In PHP, you can have a collection as an array as a class property. This collection can have a function `add` that takes multiple (type-hinted) parameters, as such: `add( Markup $markup, Style $style = Null)`, the keyword here is `Null`, the system tells you that "hey, you don't have to add this, but you can do it, but it has to be of type `Style`)" and adds a package to that internal array:

```
public function add( $name, Markup $markup, Style $style = Null )
{
    $this->packages[$name]['markup'] = $markup;

    if( $style ) {
        $this->packages[$name]['style'] = $style;
    }
}
```

Which means that 100% a package has a `markup` object, but it can have a `style` as well.

Thing is - watch what happens when, **by good intentions, I just wanna have things separated such that my interfaces aren't cluttered:**

```
public function add( $name, Markup $markup, Style $style = Null, Categorized $categories, .. )
{
    $this->packages[$name]['markup'] = $markup;

    if( $style ) {
        $this->packages[$name]['style] = $style;
    }

    if( $categories ) {
        $this->packages[$name]['categories'] = $categories;
    }

    //.. and so on, gets cluttered.
}
```

This ramps up to be Satan-level hectic to maintain.

What is a solution to this?

Comment: doesnt this overwrite the contents of packages[$name]?

Comment: Fixed. Adds to the package.

Comment: surely you should add a null style if not supplied in order to maintain the overall class

Comment: @Ewan Right, but the question is how do I do this at scale? I'll end up with a lot of parameters and a lot of checks.

Comment: why check at all, just add null

Comment: @Ewan Because it's ugly and it's not dynamic. Another developer cannot dynamically add his own stuff, he'd have to re-write this original code. I asked the next question about this in here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/403796/composing-objects-how-can-i-enforce-an-interface-upon-each-component

Comment: its less ugly, just as dynamic and they are gona have to rewrite the add function in any case?

Comment: @Ewan I moved onto that next question, add questions/comments there, please.

Answer (score 1):

Its unclear to me exactly what you are trying to do. I would have this:

```
public function add(Package $p)
{
    $this->packages[$p.name] = $p;
}

class Package
{
    public $Name
    public $Style 
    public $Categorized  
}
```